# Adding a custom filter to authentication process in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring

Right now my authentication is done with username and password. I'd like to add one more step to it so that it checks if user is activated or not. I have a user table that holds the value if the user has activated the account.

I have my SecurityConfig.java

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        // This somehow works but only if the account is not validated
        // auth.authenticationProvider(new UserActivatedAuthenticationProvider(userService));

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new ShaPasswordEncoder(encodingStrength));

}
```

And UserActivatedAuthenticationProvider.java

```
@Component
public class UserActivatedAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

private final UserService userService;

@Autowired public UserActivatedAuthenticationProvider(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    String name = authentication.getName();
    User user = userService.findByEmail(name);

    if (user != null) {
        if (!user.isActivated()) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(name + " email is not activated.");
        }
    }

    Object credentials = authentication.getCredentials();

    if (!(credentials instanceof String)) {
        return null;
    }

    String password = credentials.toString();
    Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password);

    return auth;
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}

}
```

I want to proceed with authentication only if the account is activated. I can't use `userService` in `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` because I can't get the username. I am using [this project](https://github.com/nydiarra/springboot-jwt) as a seed. In short... I also want to check the value of `is_activated` column and proceed based on that value as it now does (username and password validation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an `AuthenticationProvider`. You need to implement the `UserDetailsService` as following;

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
                        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findByEmail(username);
        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);   
        }

        return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, user.getPassword(), user.isActivated(), true, true, true, user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> role.getRoleName()).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));

    }
}
```

The spring class `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` as an property named `enabled` for which you can pass your `user.isActivated()` flag from database.

Comment: Thank you so much! The `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` requires `Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities` so I had to add my roles like this `List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

        user.getRoles().forEach(role -> {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName()));
        });` 
It works perfectly now :)

Comment: Don't use `List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>(); user.getRoles().forEach(role -> { authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName())); });` as it is a side effect. See the updated code

Comment: `user.getRoles().map(role -> role.getRoleName()).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList())` gives me two errors: `Cannot resolve method 'map(<lambda expression>)'` and `Cannot resolve method 'getRoleName()'`

Comment: I think I got it... I changed it to `user.getRoles().stream().map(Role::getRoleName).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList())` and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by providing your custom user details service.

```
@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService ;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {    
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService ).passwordEncoder(new ShaPasswordEncoder(encodingStrength));

}
```

and

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
                        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findByEmail(username);
        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);   
        }

            Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();        
            GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER");
            authorities.add(grantedAuthority);
        return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, user.getPassword(), user.isActivated(), true, true, true, authorities );

    }
}
```

Now based on Boolean value of third param, spring security will auto allow/deny user login and will also give the message "User disabled" if user is not activated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) It solved the problem I was having :)